# Date variable getting set to nil when I use it's value to create an object Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason, when I try and create a new object called "newEvent" and I pass the constructor a date from a UIDate picker, the value is set to nil for some reason, even though when I print the date value on the line before I create the object

```
print(datePicker.date)
```

The output is

```
2021-05-17 14:58:08 +0000
```

which is what it should be, but for whatever reason, when datePicker.date is used to create an object,

```
    let newEvent = Event()
    newEvent.date = datePicker.date
```

[the date variable of the object is always nil.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxEtI.png)

How can I fix this bug?

**NewEvent View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class NewEventVC: UIViewController
{
        
    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        datePicker.date = selectedDate
    }
    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let newEvent = Event()
        newEvent.id = eventsList.count
        newEvent.name = eventName.text
        print(datePicker.date)
        newEvent.date = datePicker.date
        
        eventsList.append(newEvent)
        
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to show us all of your code.

Comment: Show a [mre]. Depending on where you break execution, the debugger is also not necessarily the best place to try to see if this is nil. For example, if you break on the line of assignment, the debugger may show `nil`.

Comment: @Rudedog just updated the post with the complete class

Comment: Are you sure it’s nil, sometimes the debugger says a property is nil when it really isn’t? Try to print newEvent.date directly after you set it.